# Argument 1 passed to App\Models\User::hasAnyRoles() must be of the type array, string given

Tags: laravel-8, laravel-gate

i want to limit admins from accessing certain pages and am getting this error after running my code:
Argument 1 passed to App\Models\User::hasAnyRoles() must be of the type array, string given, called in F:\Main Server\htdocs\voskillproject\app\Providers\AuthServiceProvider.php on line 33 (View: F:\Main Server\htdocs\voskillproject\resources\views\backend\adminsidebar.blade.php)

here is my user model

```
public function roles(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Role');

}

/**
 * check if the user has a role
 * @param string $role
 * @return bool
 */
public function hasAnyRole(string $role)
{
    return null !== $this->roles()->where('Role_name',$role)->first();
}

/**
 * check if the user has any given role
 * @param array $role
 * @return bool
 */
public function hasAnyRoles(array $role)
{
    return null !== $this->roles()->whereIn('Role_name',$role)->first();
}
```

here is my authserviceprovider where i registered my gate

```
  Gate::define('is-admin',function($user)
  {
    return $user->hasAnyRoles('Super Admin','Company Manager');
  });
```

here is the navbar section

```
  @can('is-admin')
    <li class="nav-item {{ 'admin/roles'==request()->path()?'active':' ' }}">
      <a class="nav-link" href="{{ route('roles.index') }}">
        <i class="mdi mdi-view-headline menu-icon"></i>
        <span class="menu-title">Roles</span>
      </a>
    </li>
  @endcan
```

i've not understood where i did wrong on my code

Comment: The only defined argument of `hasAnyRoles()` is `array $role`, so why are you passing 2 arguments to it via `hasAnyRoles('Super Admin','Company Manager');`? That should be `hasAnyRoles(['Super Admin','Company Manager']);`... Your error is pretty clear about this.

Comment: Yeah I get you on this.actually your answer is right I had forgotten to make it into an array

Comment: No worries, it happens  Your answer below is also somewhat correct; you'd be able to do `$user->hasAnyRole('Super Admin') || $user->hasAnyRole('Company Manager')`, which would be equivalent to `$user->hasAnyRoles(['Super Admin', 'Company Manager'])`; 2nd approach is cleaner and uses less DB calls, but they'd both work.

Answer (score 0):

i found the solution in the authserviceprovider instead of hasAnyRoles it should be hasAnyRole